Проблема в драйверах для Python Selenium
Я делаю чат-бота с использованием Selenium, и получилось запустить только для Firefox, а как назло на нём моя общая идея не работает. Вообще нужно проматывать вниз Яндекс картинки, и кроме Selenium ничего не нашёл. Лучше Opera, но с ним Selenium вообще не работает, для Edge драйвер запускается только на Windows 10, а нужно на Windows Server 2012, ну а для Chrome драйвер не найти, там только старые версии и под 32 бит, а найти старую подобную версию хрома не получается. Может кто знает как обойти всё это?

Разве тут нет необходимого драйвера? https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
Пользуюсь Selenium на c# и при обновлении браузера, всегда беру хром драйвер по ссылке что привел выше.

Да я оттуда пробовал, всегда вылазит ошибка что не подходит под винду

WinServ, chrome и приложение пайтона все в x64?

Да, все на 64 версии

Покажите саму ошибку, так же можете попробовать найти тут нужную версию Google Chrome: https://google-chrome.ru.uptodown.com/windows/versions
Интересная ситуация, самому хочется разобраться почему так, на сколько я помню, selenium работает везде где есть Java и у меня самого никогда не возникало проблем с запуском

Если задача стоит в том, что бы просто проматывать картинки и Вы пользуетесь пайтоном, почему бы не попробовать скролить страницу с помощью самого пайтона? На сколько я помню, там есть возможность манипулировать действиями мыши

Вот ошибка OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32

Так там не просто проматывать, а нужно ещё находить и нажимать кнопки Показать ещё и Ещё картинки, это уже всё сделано в Selenium и отлично работает, но только в firefox

Хотя ещё вопрос - а можно Chrome запустить с плагином? В Firefox я это делаю через профиль. А в хроме я чтото подобной системы профилей не вижу

Да, можно запустить с плагином,
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_extension('./exampleOfExtensionDownloadedToFolder.crx')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('http://www.google.com')

Странно... я сейчас создал с этим кодом новый проект, и в папку не клал драйвер, и не указывал путь, и он открыл хром, это на винде 10, а на сервере всё та же ошибка. У меня кстати на сервере не получается обновить хром, может поэтому? И получается хром можно открывать без драйвера?

На сколько я помню, хром может открыться без драйвера, но работать вроде как ничего не будет. Вероятно просто когда Вы запустили на win10, Ваша среда подтянула драйвер из другого места возможно. А Вы пробовали не пытаться обновить хром на сервере, а полностью удалить, скачать на своей локальной машине последнюю сборку и закинуть на сервер? И уже там установить последнюю сборку

Спасибо за помощь, но как оказалось нужно явно указывать путь к драйверу. Это для Firefox достаточно кинуть драйвер в папку с проектом

А можно ли на удалённом компьютере после завершения сеанса кликать мышью? А то я хочу у хрома запустить расширение с помощью клика, при открытом сеансе работает, а при закрытом нет. А то что-то других способов запуска расширения я не найду

У меня работает драйвер если я просто скидываю его в папку =) Возможно в пайтоне как-то иначе. А кликать мышью да можно, воспользуйтесь средствами самого пайтона, отслеживайте когда селениум выполнит задачу, после чего воспользуйтесь средствами пайтона что бы сделать нужные клики по координатам

import pyautogui
Получаем размеры экрана
screen_width, screen_height = pyautogui.size()
Вычисляем координаты центра экрана
center_x = screen_width // 2
center_y = screen_height // 2
Выполняем клик в центре экрана
pyautogui.click(center_x, center_y)
